# Which dimension did the radioactive spider which bit Miles come from?

Tags: plot-explanation, spider-man-into-the-spider-verse

In the movie *Spider-Man: Into the Spider-Verse*, after being bitten by the radioactive spider, Miles go back to his graffiti to check the dead spider again. At this point the spider is shown glitching before Miles discover the secret laboratory.

So does this mean the radioactive spider is from a different dimension? Since only different spider-people are sucked out of their dimension, does this mean in this spider's dimension, it hasn't yet bitten it's spider-person?

Comment: That glitch seems more like getting spider-sense kind of visions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comic states that the Radioactive spider was created by experimenting on Peter Parker's blood (by Oscorp). However, there is no mention of this in the movie whatsoever.

There are two possibilities:
1) That the spider in the film was also part of some lab experiments based on the blood of Peter Parker of that universe (the one who dies).

2) That the spider came from another universe. The question then is "how did the spider get to the universe before the portal was opened?". The answer to that would be "The spider came from another universe **and** traveled back in time just like Gwen did".

However, to keep things simple, we can assume that Oscorp was up to no good and were experimenting with Peter's blood and Miles got bit by it. We already know that happened in the comics.

Comment: On watching the movie a second time, the spider doesn't seem to be from another universe, because the number of dimensions opened (as stated by Doc Oc as it was happening) matched up with the number of new spider-people who came into the current dimension.

Comment: Where are you getting that Gwen traveled back in time, is that stated somewhere in the film?  Oscorp must have been experimenting with the portal for a while, she could have just come over during one of the earlier tests.

Comment: @sirjonsnow, Gwen specifically mentions that she got thrown back in time by around a week.

Answer (score 0):

So the movie makes clear that you could be thrown into a different time from when the explosion happens, from what we see with Gwen. It also makes clear that the Spiderperson and the Spider are kind of linked, when Peter went in and his different "copies" came out they also brought Penny Parker and her Spider along with it, not just Penny. So I am theorizing if there is a dimension where the Spider exists but for what ever reason Spiderperson does not, then only the spider will come through. Thats my theory anyway.